# How to show ads to only show ads to nom-logged in users?

Tags: wordpress, web, ads

I use WordPress for my website, [What If? HQ](https://whatifhq.com) and I want to show ads to only people that are not logged in.  I searched searched on Google, stack, and Reddit and didn't find any solution to this.  Please help! Thanks

Comment: How are ads displayed ? Manually or using a plugin ? If it's manually, simple use `is_user_logged_in()`

Comment: Oh. Haha Thanks.  I didn't think it would be that simple.